# Best way to post to a wamp database from mobile app

Tags: rest, cakephp, wamp

I'm setting up a website using CakePHP and a corresponding mobile application. At various times, I need the mobile application to post information to the website and have that information be stored in a database table. I've looked at RESTful APIs and how to use them in CakePHP but I'm not sure if that's what I want. Most of the information I've read seems to indicate that RESTful APIs are helpful for getting information from the server to the client, not vice versa.

Can somebody point me in the right direction for how to do this? Let me know if I was being ambiguous or you need more information. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, read again about RESTful webservices, try this section:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs

You use the HTTP methods [GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_APIs) to read, update, create or delete resources from your site. [The RESTful page in the official CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html) explains that concept with examples pretty well.